# MapBox: How to remove a shape and draw another shape?

Tags: ios, dictionary, mapbox

I created annotation for shape

```
    _path = [RMAnnotation annotationWithMapView:_mapView
                                         coordinate: _userLocation.coordinate
                                           andTitle:@"Path"];
     [_mapView addAnnotation:_path];
```

in delegate I wrote

```
- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation
{
    if ([annotation.title isEqualToString:@"Path"])
    {
        _lineBetweenTwoBeacon = [[RMShape alloc] initWithView:mapView];
        _lineBetweenTwoBeacon.lineColor = [UIColor redColor];
        _lineBetweenTwoBeacon.lineWidth =  10.0f;
        return _lineBetweenTwoBeacon;
    }
    else
    {
    marker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"userPin"]];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    marker.leftCalloutAccessoryView = imageView;
    return marker;
    }
}
```

Next step I draw shape

```
[_lineBetweenTwoBeacon addQuadCurveToCoordinate:firstBeaconCoord controlCoordinate:secondBeaconCoord];
```

But how to remove all shapes from the map and add new shape.
Now the shape lay to the shape, it's not correct.
Will be better if  _lineBetweenTwoBeacon redraw every time.

Thank you, for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you manually create an `RMShape`, you need to tell it where to move and to draw after creating it with methods like `-moveToCoordinate:` and `-addLineToCoordinate:`. If you just have basic needs, I would recommend trying `RMPolylineAnnotation`, which handles the drawing for you.

Comment: RMPolylineAnnotation it's very simple!
Thank you so much!