# Dynamically draw RMShape according to user location

Tags: ios, mapbox

I'm creating an array representing a path made by the user by adding the user's current location to an array. Each time a new point is being added, I remove the previous annotation, and add a new one. then the new path is being drawn on a mapView with `RMShape` and `layerForAnnotation`. The problem is that every time the `RMSape` layer is being drawn, it has like a slide transition.

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I fix this "slide" effect, and draw a continuous line representing the user's path smoothly?
2. Is there a better way for tracing user's path?

.

```
-(void)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(RMUserLocation *)userLocation
{

        if (path) {
            [self.mapView removeAnnotation:path];
        }

        path = [[RMShapeAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:mapView points:points];

        [mapView addAnnotation:path];

}



- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation
{

    if (annotation.isUserLocationAnnotation) {
        return nil;
    }

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[RMShapeAnnotation class]]) {

        for (int i = 0; i < points.count; i++) {
            CLLocation *location = points[i];
            [self.path addLineToCoordinate:location.coordinate];

         }

        return self.path;

    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it will help you! Use RMPolylineAnnotation to draw simple line.
When I drew line, I removed RMPolylineAnnotation and added new RMPolylineAnnotation with increased cordite.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254551/mapbox-how-to-remove-a-shape-and-draw-another-shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would update your annotation layer directly as opposed to constantly replacing your annotation and thus its layer. You can do this by obtaining `annotation.layer`, casting it to `RMShape`, and then using methods like `-addLineToCoordinate:` to update it.